# Airflow - skip DAG if sensor failed

Tags: airflow

I have process where I'm waiting for a file every week, but this file is timestamped in its name for the mesurment's date. So I know I'm going to have something this week and the name can be 2020-05-25*.csv up to 2020-05-31*.csv.

The only way I find out to start my processes with airflow is to run a sensor at start @daily and using the executing date to find is there is a file.
The thing is, since I don't know which day the file will be uploaded I will have 6 fails sensors, so 6 failed DAGs, and 1 succeeded.

SFTP Sensors part exemple :

```
with DAG(
        "geometrie-sftp-to-safe",
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval="@daily",
        catchup=True,
) as dag:
    starting_sensor = DummyOperator(
        task_id="starting_sensor"
    )

    sensor_sftp_A = SFTPSensor(
        task_id="sensor_sftp_A",
        path="/input/geometrie/prod/Track_Geometry-{{ ds_nodash }}_A.csv",
        sftp_conn_id="ssh_ftp_landing",
        poke_interval=60,
        soft_fail=True,
        mode="reschedule"
    )
```

Second With GCSSensor

```
with DAG(
        "geometrie-preprocessing",
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval="@daily",
        catchup=True
) as dag:
    # File A
    sensor_gcs_A = GoogleCloudStorageObjectSensor(
        task_id="gcs-sensor_A",
        bucket="lisea-mesea-sea-cloud-safe",
        object="geometrie/original/track_geometry_{{ ds_nodash }}_A.csv",
        google_cloud_conn_id="gcp_conn",
        poke_interval=50
    )
```

That's why I would like the DAGs to be set as skipped, if and only if the sensor have fail. If it's something else I would like a real fail.

Comment: Can you just run the DAG at the end of the week, because otherwise you will have to differentiate two cases: nothing came today and it is not the end of the week - skip, nothing came today and it is the end of the week - fail

Comment: Use schedule_interval as None and use FileSensor operator to sense for the file in the provided directory. You have to trigger the DAG only once and it would trigger on its own whenever a new file enters in the directory. I have done the same thing using airflow for Google Cloud Storage operators but sensors and parameters are different.

Comment: I have a SFTPSensor activated. Can I have an exemple how to set it up ? While the schedule_interval set to none it will automatically trigger when a new file arrived everytime or do I have to manually trigger the dag ?

Answer (score 1):

Airflow has multiple sensors which senses the directory to check for the defined file. The schedule_interval as None will work to your use case as you want the DAG to trigger only when the file is received(considering that the file can be received anytime within the week).

The below example for GCSSensor will sense the bucket for the particular type of file and will print the filename.I am pretty sure that SFTP sensor should work the same way.

```
dag = DAG(
 dag_id='sensing-bucket',
 schedule_interval=None,
 default_args=args)

def new_file_detection(**context):
    value = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='list_Files')
    print('value is : '+str(value))

File_sensor = GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor(
                task_id='gcs_polling',
                bucket='lisea-mesea-sea-cloud-safe',
                prefix='geometrie/original/track_geometry_',
                dag=dag
            )

GCS_File_list = GoogleCloudStorageListOperator(
                    task_id='list_Files',
                    bucket='lisea-mesea-sea-cloud-safe',
                    prefix='geometrie/original/track_geometry_',
                    delimiter='.csv',
                    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
                    dag=dag
                )

File_detection = PythonOperator(
                task_id='print_detected_filename',
                provide_context=True,
                python_callable=new_file_detection,
                dag=dag
            )

File_sensor >> GCS_File_list >> File_detection
```

Comment: How can I get the last uploaded file with this ?

Comment: Are you planning to keep the file in the same bucket even if they are processed? In that case, DAG will pickup the files again as the criteria will be met. If you want to see last uploaded file then use 'is_updated_after' in GoogleCloudStorageHook:  https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcs_hook/index.html#airflow.contrib.hooks.gcs_hook.GoogleCloudStorageHook.is_updated_after